# jQuery validation plugin and regular expression

Tags: jquery, regex

Why following code return `true` with value "my@cool.email" (more than a 4 characters after last dot) ?
Pattern `/^([a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})*$/` work correct in my php-scripts and regex101.com (regexp tester).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.validator.addMethod("pattern", function(value, element, param) {
        if (this.optional(element)) {
            return true;
            }
        if (typeof param === "string") {
            param = new RegExp("^(?:" + param + ")$");
            }
            return param.test(value);
            }, "Invalid format");
    $('.form-register').validate({
        rules:{            
            email:{
                required: true,
                pattern: "([a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{1,4})*"
                }
        messages:{
            email:{
                pattern: "Invalid email"
                }
             });
         });
```

.....

```
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="eMail" required="required">
```

Comment: Please don't validate emails this way. `my@cool.email` is valid email.

Comment: Of course you're right. Let's call "email" simply "string"?

Answer (score 0):

You should use this syntax for regexes:

```
var pattern = /[a-z]/;
```

Try to remove question marks from your expression.

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_regexp.asp

Comment: I removed the question marks - not rectified the situation. Pattern "[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9._]+" in same script works completely correct

Answer (score 0):

The regex is working:

```
if (/^([a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})*$/.test("my@cool.email")) {
  alert("True");
} else {
  alert("False");
}
```

---

Try to add ^ and $ to your regex in the script.

---

If you use this it works:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $.validator.addMethod("pattern", function(value, element, param) {
            if (this.optional(element)) {
                return true;
                }
            if (typeof param === "string") {
                param = new RegExp("^(?:" + param + ")$");
                }
            return param.test(value);
            }, "Invalid regular expression format");
            $('.form-register').validate({
                rules:{
                    login:{
                        required: true,
                        pattern: "[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9._]+",
                        minlength: 3
                    },
                    email:{
                        required: true,
                        pattern: /^([a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})*$/
                    },
                },
                messages:{
                    login:{         
                        pattern: "Ivalid login"
                    },
                    email:{
                        required: "required",
                        pattern: "Ivalid email"
                    },

                }
            });
        });
```